# EXPO dev-client on IOS not working on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo, expo-dev-client

Currently I'm experiencing a weird error when I try to use dev-client on my device (iphone), I was able to install the dev-client and run the server, but when I scan the generated QR code, it stays in the splash screen for a few seconds and then throws me an error:
"No bundle URL present
Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle"

I'm running the command expo start --dev-client and I have my mac and Iphone connected to the same internet connection

When I try to open in my Ios simulator, it works fine, anyone has any clues of what can be causing it?

I'm using EAS Build to generate the build.

I followed every step of the documentation, already tried cleaning the cache, rebuilding the dev-client, but nothing worked